# Is there an application area that sensors are on planes and we know the local positions of the sensors, but not the global positions?

Tags: reference-request

I am currently writing the motivation of my thesis. And the answer to this question is very crucial for me:

I am working on wireless sensor networks.
Say that, there are a number of planes, for instance rooms inside a building. 
There are sensors on these planes.
Is there any application area or sceniaro that gives me the local positions (positions on the planes) of the sensor but not the global positions?

In other words, can you tell me a scenario that we don't know where the sensors are (or which plane they are on) in 3D but we know where they are on their own plane?

Comment: I suppose you should find such scenarios in the related papers of your thesis.

Comment: @seteropere I could not. That's why I ask for your help.